# Unable to tweak theme settings unless I start a new session

Tags: init-file, themes, daemon

I have this code in my init.el file, mainly to apply the theme correctly when running emacs server:

```
    ;; This will make sure the theme loads well in emacs daemon 
    (setq myGraphicModeHash (make-hash-table :test 'equal :size 2))
    (puthash "gui" t myGraphicModeHash)
    (puthash "term" t myGraphicModeHash)
    (defun emacsclient-setup-theme-function (frame)
      (let ((gui (gethash "gui" myGraphicModeHash))
            (ter (gethash "term" myGraphicModeHash)))
        (progn
          (select-frame frame)
          (when (or gui ter) 
            (progn
              ;; setup the smart-mode-line and its theme
              (setq sml/no-confirm-load-theme t)
              (sml/setup)
              (sml/apply-theme 'dark)
              (load-theme 'material t)
              (if (display-graphic-p)
                  (puthash "gui" nil myGraphicModeHash)
                (puthash "term" nil myGraphicModeHash))))
          (when (not (and gui ter))
            (remove-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'emacsclient-setup-theme-function)))))
    (if (daemonp)
        (add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'emacsclient-setup-theme-function)
      (progn 
        (setq sml/no-confirm-load-theme t)
        (sml/setup)
        (load-theme 'material t)
        ))
```

I also have this code to tweak some of material theme face fonts:

```
;; Material theme
(use-package material-theme
  :ensure t
  :defer t
  :config
  (set-face-attribute
   'font-lock-comment-face  nil :foreground "#69B7F0" :background "#00629D" :bold t)
  (set-face-attribute
   'font-lock-constant-face nil :foreground "#69B7F0" :background "#00629D" :bold t))
```

However, the changes to lock_comment and lock_constant are not being applied unless I start a new frame. Any pointers on why that is and how to fix it?

Comment: Why are you loading a theme every time you create a frame, instead of doing that one time only?

Comment: I actually picked this code from stackoverflow, not sure what it dos exactly, but it fixed the theme I have when running in daemon. However, I picked another fix that seems to apply the theme when running emacs, but still not applying it when running a server. I have updated the question. Would really appreciate your input.